# Multiplicative cohomology theories and smash products

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, cw-complexes

In his [student guide](http://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/mathematics/geometry-and-topology/algebraic-topology-students-guide) on page 154, Adams gives a construction of products for cohomology using "pairings" of spectra (now known as maps from $E\wedge E\to E$). But then he says

> However, G. W. Whitehead did not say (because it is not
>   true) that every product in generalised cohomology theory arises
>   from a pairing in this sense.

On the other hand, if $E$ is a CW-spectrum (as in Adams' [Chicago lecture notes](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/S/bo21302708.html)), one can turn it into an $\omega$-spectrum in the category of CW-spectra using Milnor's theorem. Then each product in the corresponding generalized cohomology theory tautologically defines maps $E_k\wedge E_\ell\to E_{k+\ell}$.

Thus my questions: What examples have G. W. Whitehead and J. F. Adams been thinking of? In which situations would the naïve Argument above fail?

Comment: Related: such maps define a product on a spectrum under additional conditions which are explained in Switzer, theorem 13.80.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do not claim that I know what Adams meant; for all I know his definition of "product" may include products which are not bilinear. Take the following with a grain of salt.

What I suspect is the following. Adams says, just before your quote:

"In order to construct such products, G.W. Whitehead introduced the notion of a 'pairing of spectra'. A pairing of spectra from $E$ and $F$ to $G$, in the sense of G.W. Whitehead, consists of maps
$$
\mu_{n,m}: E_n \wedge F_m \to G_{n+m}
$$
which satisfy suitable axioms..." (Said suitable axioms appearing in detail in Whitehead's paper "[Generalized homology theories](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/gww9.pdf)".)

Adams then describes the pairing on complex cobordism as arising from maps $MU_n \wedge MU_m \to MU_{n+m}$.

I suspect that what Adams meant is that, given spectra $E$, $F$, and $G$, there may be pairings from $E$ and $F$ to $G$ which do not arise from maps of the above *specific* type: for example, if you skipped the step of replacing $G$ with an $\Omega$-spectrum, or don't adopt the "cells now, maps later" methodology, some needed targets for maps from $E_n \wedge F_m$ may be missing. For example, the stable Hopf map $\eta \in \pi_2^{stable}(S^1)$ cannot be represented by a pairing from $\Sigma^\infty S^1$ and $\Sigma^\infty S^1$ to $\Sigma^\infty S^1$.

Comment: This is at least partially supported by his statement afterwards: that as a result of not every pairing being defined like this, we would like a definition of $E \wedge F$ as a "spectrum in good standing".

Comment: I see. I somehow suspected that Adams' remark might make more sense in its historical context than from our modern perspective. I was still kind of hoping for a somewhat more general notion of a product, though.